# Curl return false on hostinger server (curl enabled)

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, vk, vk-sdk

Using:

> hostinger free
>   php 5.5.26
>   curl  enabled 7.19.7
>   "laravel/framework": "5.2.*" and "vladkens/vk": "^0.1.9"

I'm getting false response(`bool(false)`) using this function:

```
private function request($url, $method = 'GET', $postfields = array())
{
    curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT =>"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POST => ($method == 'POST'),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url
    ));

    return curl_exec($this->ch);
}
```

Using `curl_getinfo($this->ch)` getting this debugging data:

```
array(23) { ["url"]=> string(251) "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.search.json?access_token={{access_token}}&api_id={{api_id}}&q=21+Hunter+Hayes&random=1014×tamp=1453393550&v=2.0&sig={{sig}}" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } }
```

And if I use from this array directly in browser `url` value I will get proper api.vk.com reponse with data.

What I'm missing?
**UPDATE:**
Getting this message `couldn't connect to host` using`echo $error = curl_error($this->ch);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem unable to reach internet from your server.
It sounds like a firewall issue. 
Go to your panel and ensure there are no firewall rules preventing you from acessing outside web sites. It could be a limitation due to your hosting plan.

Comment: yes, you are right. I contacted IT support and [hostinger](http://hostinger.com.) preventing you from accessing outside web sites with php curl functionality on free plan.