# PHP cURL working in localhost but not working on Server

Tags: php, curl, xampp, hosting

My source code is running 100% good when it is only on my localhost (XAMPP) but when I upload it my source code doesn't curl the sites, it cannot also provide any output. By the way I only upload my sample site to Hostinger.

[image]

Comment: Please add details about your code, your server, and what exactly doesn't work... here, we can't guess...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl return false on hostinger server (curl enabled)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929470/curl-return-false-on-hostinger-server-curl-enabled)

Comment: firstly check if your server is enabled with curl http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php, if that is not the case then please check for error http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-strerror.php

Comment: I checked already and it is stated that the curl is enabled

Comment: but still my source code doesn't work.

Comment: @wrines wr ines checked for error ?? still issue is there, then please paste the code here. Without that its difficult to find the issue.

Comment: sorry  @user2314870 I am just only a beginner. but I try to catch the error using this code  echo error_reporting(E_ALL);    and it provides an output of 32759

Comment: Am I correct? or Just doing a mess?. if i am wrong please give me the sample code to get the error message so that I can provide you the error.

Comment: @wrines wr ines just post the code below in answer please check and let me know if your query is resolved or not

Answer (score 1):

just checked your code, please add below lines at the end, you will come to know what is the error

```
if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
else{
    echo $content;  
}
```

replace `$ch` with `$handle` and also remove init_set function as of now

Output is

```
error:Could not resolve host: wwww.todayhumor.co.kr
```

Please check and confirm the Url

Comment: @wrines wr ines there is some issue with url, try paste the same URL in browser you will come to know

Comment: Thank you @user2314870 for your time but still I cannot find the answer.

Comment: @wrines wr ines the error says it can't resolve the URL your code is okay, there issue with the URL that you are passing within cURL

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that curl is not enabled on your hosting server, you can see if that's the problem by using the `phpinfo()` function and you will be displayed everything that is enabled.

If it's not contact your hosting or change it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a missing `}` in `for` loop. But if it is just a typo,
try to separate curl codes from your `for` loop.

You can move them to a function like this:

```
...
$link=...
curl_call($link);
```

Comment: sorry, It is just only a typographical error. but when I do what you are advising me still doesn't work