# Why PHP Curl works locally, but not on free host (000webhost and hostinger)?

Tags: php, curl, localhost, web-hosting

I have this code that works OK on my USBWebServerV8:

```
<?php

$url = "http://mobile.detran.ce.gov.br";

$curl_log = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Android SDK built for x86 Build/KK)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '5');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: mobile.detran.ce.gov.br'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR ,$curl_log);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT );
print "<br/>".curl_error($ch)."<br/>";

print $headerSent."<br/>";
echo "<pre>". print_r($page, 1). "</pre>"."<br/>";

?>
```

But when I try to run the same code hosted (free plan) at www.000webhost.com and www.hostinger.com it gives me either a timeout ( 000webhost ) or a internal server error ( hostinger ).

Why would the same PHP code works locally but not at a free host?

Also, I tried to log but somehow my logging code above is not working as expected, it creates a file "request.txt" that is keeps blank after my requests.

Comment: the problem might be the hosting server.

Comment: Maybe but I think curl is a Very popular And usefull library  that should not be blocked nor limited. Any suggestion for Free PHP hosts that fully support curl?

Comment: the free accounts are on and off, they work, sometimes they don't

Comment: Free hosts attract bad people looking to use it for spamming, scraping, attacks, etc. They'll typically be massively locked down. You get what you pay for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is likely an issue with the hosting provider rather than the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They block for outbound traffic. 000webhost said they blocked because of "too many phishing attacks".

Sources:

- [Source support 000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/curl-not-working-disabled-broken/33894/7)
- [Stack Overflow question about hostinger curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929470/curl-return-false-on-hostinger-server-curl-enabled)

Comment: even this for paíd accounts?

Comment: Probably not: "Due to abuse the services are being turn off. This is the trend of many free hosting service.".

Comment: Any suggestion for Free PHP hosts that fully support curl?

Comment: Amazon AWS give you 1 year free: https://aws.amazon.com/free/. You will have a server for you, but it is not as simple as 000webhost and hostinger.

Comment: ,thank you for pointing me to the explanations about why curl is being blocked to avoid abuse but what about my code itself? is it OK ? regarding the logging is OK too ? Can I consider that the issue is only at the hosting provider?

Comment: You are welcome :)
I had no problem with your code (i tested it locally before searching any problem about the providers). Your logging is ok. But i think you should check also error.log file (this is from the provider). If you use AWS + Apache for your php, you should check your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (the file will be different for others http servers, like nginx).

Comment: Do You know If a paíd plan of that two hosters mentioned on this post  Will allow for sure the use of curl ? If só, can You point me to where I can confirm that information?

Comment: @CaioMaia ASK THE HOST. That said, AWS is a full VPS provider - as long as you install the cURL PHP extension (that's on you) you're good.